# Why does iCloud mail badge push notification updating not work

Tags: iphone, icloud, mail.app, notifications

I’m looking for a good reason to move to iCloud from Fastmail but testing out iCloud, I am perplexed why when opening new mail on my iPad for instance, doesn’t update the read badge on the iPhone in background (without opening the mail app). Seems like a no brainer unless I am doing it wrong.